# How both asterisked lines are correct given the SQL statement

Tags: sql, select

A new social network site has the following data tables:

Table **users**:

| id | name | sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann | null |
| 2 | Steve | m |
| 3 | Mary | f |
| 4 | Brenda | f |

Table **friends**:

| user1 | user2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

Select data that will be returned by the following SQL query:

```
  SELECT users.name, 
         COUNT(*) as count 
    FROM users LEFT JOIN 
         friends ON users.id = friends.user1 OR users.id = friends.user2
   WHERE users.sex = 'f'
GROUP BY users.id, 
         users.name;
```

**Output**:

| name | count |
| --- | --- |
| Ann | 1 |
| Ann | 2 |
| Steve | 1 |
| Steve | 2 |
| Mary | 1 |
| Mary | 2 ** |
| Brenda | 0 |
| Brenda | 1 ** |

The asterisked sections are the correct answers, but I don't quite understand why (Brenda, 1) would be an answer here when (Mary, 2) is also a correct answer.

Comment: "The asterisked sections are the **correct answers**" - what is the initial *question*, please?

Comment: Get rid of the counting and grouping and include all column in the `SELECT` clause. Examine that result set. You should then understand what's happening when `GROUP BY` is applied. Hint - `COUNT(*)` is never going to return 0 in this query.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I understand they are correct but I just wasn't sure why Brenda,1 was correct.  I thought the answers would have been just Mary,2.  My reasoning behind this was that Brenda's id was not present in the friends table. Is it due to using a left join here specifically?

Comment: why has brenda count of 1? see is not in the friends table

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think I understand.  So the reason why we get brenda,1 here is due to how the group by clause functions.  Even adding a record into the friends table so brenda had a friend associated to her user the output would still be brenda,1.  Only increasing to brenda,2 when there were at least 2 entries.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you reply with that so I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

This is a trap question. The query looks like your are selecting all female users (`sex = 'f'`) and count their friendships. For this a left outer join on the friends table is applied, so we keep all female users, no matter whether they have friendships or not.

But then the query uses `COUNT(*)`, which counts the joined rows. That is 2 for Mary and 1 for Brenda. If we wanted to count friendships, we'd have to count a column of the friends table, e.g. `COUNT(friends.user1)`. Thus the outer joined rows having these columns set to null would be omitted from the count, and we'd get 2 for Mary and 0 for Brenda.